# How to fill a cell range with a single value with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, excel-2016

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('PathToFile')
sht = wb['SheetName']
rge = sht['k1:k999']
```

I would like to fill every cell in "rge" (i.e. k1, k2, ..., k999) with the string "...".

I found an easy way with xlwings, but I would prefer to use openpyxl, since openpyxl can be used on both Windows and GNU/Linux:

```
sht.range('k1:k999').value='...'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iter_rows() may be a choice for you. Please find [this link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) for more details.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('PathToFile')
sht = wb['SheetName']

for row in sht.iter_rows('K1:K999'):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = '...'

wb.save('PathToFile')
```

Comment: Thanks Kaitlyn, it works fine. However `iter_row` seems deprecated, I used `sht['K1:K999']:` instead of `sht.iter_rows('K1:K999'):`